# How to send a XML file to RabbitMQ using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, rabbitmq, send, rabbitmq-exchange

I am  having an xml file called `Test.xml`  which I am trying to send RabbitMQ using python.

I know below deatails regarding the Rabbit MQ

```
Hostname: xxx.xxxx.xxx

AMQP Port (SSL)  :4589

ESB Portal (Message Search): http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8585

RabbitMQ Web UI (https) :https://xxx.xxx.xxxx:15672
```

How can this be done from python?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Their documentation is pretty good. What issues are you having ?

Comment: @theMayer, I am also trying to do the same. I have notcoema cross anyproper document that helps to me  send file to rabbit MQ. If you could post this as anser as would be really helpfull all reades

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [pika](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), you can read the file content and send it as a big string to RabbitMQ. And on the other side you can parse the content using `ElementTree.fromstring`.

Connection details:

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')
conn = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('host', port, 'vhost', credentials))
channel = conn.channel()
```

Publisher:

```
with open('filename.xml', 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
channel.basic_publish('exchange', 'queue', ''.join(lines))
```

Consumer:

```
def on_message(unused_channel, unused_method_frame, unused_header_frame, body):
    lines = body.decode()
    doc = ElementTree.fromstring(lines)
    tags = doc.findall("tag")

    ## DO YOUR STUFF HERE

channel.basic_consume('queue', on_message)
channel.start_consuming()
```

Hope this helps!

**RabbitMQ flow:**

[image: RabbitMQ flow]

Reference: [RabbitMQ docs](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html)

Comment: can  you telll me what does  `exchange`,`queue` in busic_publish means

Comment: The `exchange` routes the messages to the `queue`. The `queue` is the name of the `queue` to which the message is to be sent

Comment: @bumblebee,If  my understanding is correct from your answer,If i am sending just xml file to RabbitMQ then `Publisher` is only needed . Also  I just need to know the hostname, port , username and password for sending the  file

Comment: @pankaj If you just want to send the contents of the XML file to the RabbitMQ queue, then `publisher` alone is enough. But queues are often associated with `consumers` which consume the messages from the queue. In order to publish or consume the message, the RabbitMQ client needs to make a `connection` to the RabbitMQ server/host. Hence you need the hostname, port and credentials

Comment: @bumblebee, Thanks great info. In my case I just  need push the xml to the MQ queue. Its an another team is responsible for reading the data from MQ. I guess  publisher is only needed

Comment: @pankaj Then publisher is what you need. Glad to help!