# Getting 'positional argument' Error while sending a XML file to RabbitMQ from Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I am trying to send a XML file to RabbitMQ from python but I am getting  the below error

**Error**

```
File "<ipython-input-134-8a1b7f8b2e41>", line 3
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='',queue='abc',''.join(lines))
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

**My Code**

```
import ssl
!pip install pika
import pika
ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(ssl._create_unverified_context())
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(username='abcc', password='abcc')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='xxxx', port=5671, virtual_host ='xxx', credentials=credentials, 
        ssl_options=ssl_options))
channel = connection.channel()
result = channel.queue_declare(queue='abc')
with open('20200205280673.xml', 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',queue='abc',''.join(lines))
```

Whats wrong in the above code?

Comment: you should use `body=''.join(lines)`... also note that this function receives array of bytes (you may convert your string to bytes). https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/channel.html#pika.channel.Channel.basic_publish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ymz suggested, you are missing the `body` key in the `basic.publish` method. Also, the `basic_publish` method has no argument called `queue`. Please have a look at its implementation [docs](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/adapters/blocking.html#pika.adapters.blocking_connection.BlockingChannel.basic_publish)

**Edit #1:** I have already answered this question elsewhere [How to send a XML file to RabbitMQ using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256957/how-to-send-a-xml-file-to-rabbitmq-using-python/60259144#60259144)

**Edit #2:** Automating publishing of XML files. Assuming all the files are present in a directory called `xml_files`

```
import os

DIR = '/path/to/xml_files'

for filename in os.listdir(DIR):
    filepath = f"{DIR}/{filename}"
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='exchange', routing_key='queue', body=''.join(lines))
```

Comment: should I convert xml to bytes format  `lines = str.encode(lines)`

Comment: @RiaAlves Updated the answer

Comment: I had reffered to that question.  You have mentioned `channel.basic_publish('exchange', 'queue', ''.join(lines))`. I guess it should `routing_key` instead of queue

Comment: The value `queue` get implicitly set on the `routing_key` key. You can also use it like `channel.basic_publish(exchange='exchange', routing_key='queue', body=''.join(lines))`

Comment: Also I docs I see`body (bytes) – The message body; empty string if no body`. Should I convert xml to bytes format ?

Comment: `pika` does this implicitly. It works for me without encoding the message as well. You can try both ways

Comment: Thanks , One last question, I have 20 xmls to transferred to MQ. Is there a way automatically pass one after other to the MQ.

Comment: If all those XML files are present in one directory, you can list down the directory, read the file content and transfer them one by one. That's all I can think of now!

Comment: @bumblebee, Can post that part as answer, I am looking for similar kind of solution , I have 1000s of XMls

Comment: @Rahulrajan Added

Comment: @bumblebee, Thanks mate. What does `exchange` in publish means

Comment: Exchanges are nothing but routers that route the given messages to a queue. Have a look at https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html